# Two dependencies containing same classes

Tags: maven, tomcat, dependencies

I have a maven project which uses libosm-2.5.2-RC1 library. This library contains osmosis library. Osmosis library is already packed in the jar file of the libosm library when libosm is downloaded. The problem is that this osmosis library is old and can not work with current OSM data. In maven I can add a new version of osmosis as a dependency, and if I put it in the POM file earlier than the libosm library then the newer classes from new osmosis are used. However when I build the project both libraries are included into lib folder. And after deploying, tomcat server uses the old osmosis that is packed in libosm.

What I want to achieve is to use libosm library but if there are classes that are both in libosm and in new osmosis library, then I want to use those from new osmosis library.

One solution that works is to manually unpack jar file of libosm and rewrite old osmosis classes with new ones. But I would like to achieve the same thing with maven, because I want to share the project and it is not comfortable for other people to manually add updated jar libosm file that i created.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not need the classes from libosm-2.5.2-RC1 and if you know the packages/classes that you don't want as part of this jar, you could strip them away in maven-jar-plugin 's package phase. This link shows how to do it. let me know if this helps. http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Excluding-packages-and-classes-from-jar-td106688.html

Comment: Thanks, but not what I am looking for. It would be helpful if it was possible to exclude classes only of one dependency(is it?). In libosm I want to exclude package org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.customdb.v0_6.impl (and many others). But in new osmosis dependency(which has the package as well) I do not want it excluded. To better describe it if I unpacked jars of both libosm and new osmosis, then I would take new osmosis files and with them I would replace all the existing files in old osmosis in libosm. However if old osmosis has other files (not present in new osmosis) I want to keep those.

Comment: very interesting situation :) basically you want to extract the old jar first, then overwrite the new one on top :) I think that's possible using some of the plugins to re-package a jar. Why not make it your own custom jar and deploy it to your local maven repo?